# Python only deserialize top layer json data

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a large number of some large json files to work with.
Unfortunately not all of the json data is well structured.

In a nutshell the data is shaped like

> `[
>       { A1:va1,
>           B:[
>               {B1:vb1, ...},
>               {B2...},
>               {...}
>           ]
>       },
>       { A2 ....},
>       {....}
>   ]`

An array of `A` objects that, among other things, contains an inner array of none-to-many `B` objects.

Unfortunately on random occasion a given `B` object will have a structural violation.

What I want to do is iterate over the `A` level but enforce the `B` objects be treated as individual strings, rather being parsed by json.loads() -or- causing json.loads() to treat each instance of a `B` as a string, so I can log the `B` strings for first-hand examination.

As I said, the data shape above is only in a nutshell.  In the real data there is A LOT more going on ambiguously at the top `A` level ~ because of that I don't think I can successfully define and apply a schema effectively to this data.  At least at the top `A` level there are not any structural violations.

Comment: Could you give an actual example of these "structural violations" you're talking about?  There's certainly no way that you're going to get `json.load()` to ignore lower-level structure, as it would have absolutely no way of knowing where a top-level object ends and the next object begins without parsing the lower-level objects.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your response.  I believe there are multiple data quality issues; missing commas between objects, between k,v pairs, duplicate key names within the same scope, ... But I can't present the actual data by agreement.
I hoping there is maybe another lib out there other than the defacto standard `json` to help?!?  I really do not want to parse this out for myself at as a lower level text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is I could examine the data with any amount of certainty.
In 15 minutes I had the answer using this approach; not the answer I wanted but at least I now know what I have to deal with.

I took one file loaded it into Notepad++ with the JSON Formatter add-in.
Formatted it and dropped that into an Excel sheet.  Added a few columns with equations to point out the lines of interest, a couple of Ctrl-F Find All, and sorts.

Now my worst case scenario is right there in front of me.  But at least I now know.